# Protecting private IP address using Google for Work's SMTP settings

Tags: ddos, gmail

We currently got a website that is protected with cloudflare, however there is one leak we found. Our server's IP is shown in email headers, which makes cloudflare kinda useless at this point. We've recently been hit by a 30gbps ddos attack on our direct ip, causing our hosting to nullroute that ip address and assign a new one. But since the IP address is still being spoofed they can just launch another attack.

We are using Google's SMTP to send our emails, so we are using an external mail server, how can I solve this issue?

Many people say that it isn't right to leave out the IP address which I understand, but if it's not left out we will constantly be a victim of ddos attacks.

Comment: Consider using something like Mandrill or Amazon SES to send email. Google's SMTP is not really intended or designed for handling your server's outgoing email.

Comment: @ceejayoz Would this solve the issue I'm experiencing? I'm not that good with servers, I'm more of a programmer.

Comment: Do you mean your _public_ IP address? You said "private", but if it were a [private address](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918), you wouldn't be receiving outside attacks on it.

Comment: Private IP as in server's IP address instead of the proxy IP @MichaelHampton

Comment: That's not a private address!

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion @MichaelHampton

Comment: @Jordy Yes, that should solve the issue.

Comment: How do you know that they're getting the IP address from your email headers?  People use scripts to scan public IP ranges for potential targets.  Yours probably came up that way instead.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Does that matter? This is one way how they got our IP address and should be fixed.

Comment: Your public IP isn't really a secret.  In my opinion, your mail header is a very unlikely source for people to get your IP.  The scripted scan scenario is a lot more likely.  You can, of course, "fix" the email header thing if it makes you feel better, but I don't think it'll do much more for you than that.

Comment: @ceejayoz I've just tested Mandrill and it still submits the server ip through Received: from header.

Comment: @Jordy So I've just tested on one of my AWS instances that uses Mandrill, and it shows `Received: by 10.182.236.65` (internal IP) then `Received: from mail177-25.suw61.mandrillapp.com`. No public IP at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFlare states in their [protecting the origin server article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/ddos-prevention-protecting-the-origin/):

> **Don't host mail or other services on the same server as your web server**
>
> If your mail server hosted by the same IP as your http server, an attacker could find the IP address from an outgoing email. For example, an attacker could send an email to a non-existent email address on your server causing a bounce; the bounce might contain the IP address of your server in its headers."

Services like [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) and [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) are available for this. Alternatively, you could set up a second server with your host and pass emails through there.

I'd make sure you've implemented the other items in that article while you're there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've tested Mandrill and they spoof IP's as well, so I guess we indeed have to setup a second server that handles outgoing mail.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Google mail as protection of DDoS attack (in term of "attackers gets my IP from emails"), this is useless. Attackers don't want to get IP somewhere - they just test all IPs on the whole Internet (IPv4 has only 2^32 possible ip addresses and only part of it is usable on the Internet), so they will sooner or later target you as anybody else. You can just handle DDoSes, you cannot avoid them.

Yes, there is very little possibility that attack is targeted directly on your company and in this term, some hiding will work. But you cannot hide it from everywhere (you will be listed at some sources, like whois or dns records). But more, more posibile is that attack is not targeted, they just find some server which can be DDoSed, so they do it (you will be surprissed how many kids are DDoSing random IPs only for fun. You can rent botnet for couple of bucks and get everything down, even google (yes, you need to have BIG botnet but it is possible)).

Comment: The thing is that this was a targetted attack, the user who ddosed us contacted me, and gave me all the details, and he said that he got the IP through image uploading and email, I've tackled image uploading now just need to get the email tackled.

Comment: So next time they will just send email to anybody in company with image linked from attackers server and they know your IP too. You cannot hide your IP, there is way how to get it. Anytime.

Comment: Then what is the point of cloudflare? It's a proxy that hides your IP. Oh and our server is not hosted at our company, it's hosted elsewhere. Isn't cloudflare completely useless then?

Comment: No, you didn't understand cloudflare completelly - cloudflare is caching proxy before your servers. It process requests and detect which URL is requested, transmit it to original (=your) server and cache result, so 1) it can spread your site across the globe (visitors from Australia doesn't need to reach server in USA) 2) it can cache results, so your server doesn't need to server same content again and again (= your server can handle more unique requests) and 3) it can serve your website if your server is down (= visitors will not notice problem on your server at all).Nothing about hiding IP.

Comment: But cloudflare also serves DDOS protection, so that's not the only thing it does.

Comment: @jordy but that is a by product of the service they offer rather then the main point

Comment: @OndraSniperFlidr "So next time they will just send email to anybody in company with image linked from attackers server and they know your IP too." will only work if the office IP is the same as the webserver. Usually, the webserver is hosted in a datacenter somewhere.

Comment: @Drifter104 No, it's a stated feature of theirs. https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/ Their blog often details the large attacks they prevent (https://blog.cloudflare.com/technical-details-behind-a-400gbps-ntp-amplification-ddos-attack/) and they offer advice on hiding the origin server (https://blog.cloudflare.com/ddos-prevention-protecting-the-origin/).

Comment: @ceejayoz you misunderstand what I mean. Yes it is a feature, but it is their proxy system that allows them to offer it. If they didn't do the proxying they couldn't offer ddos protection

Comment: @Drifter104 It's certainly not "a by product of the service".

Comment: @ceejayoz tbh neither of us know what came first in the list of products. So neither of us came claim it either way for certain

Comment: @Drifter104 CloudFlare's launch announcement in 2010 included DDOS prevention as one of their primary features. Sorry, but continuing to move the goalposts isn't working.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm not moving the goal posts, I stand by what I said. when I said what came first, I meant from a design point of view, not what was launched. I'm simply drawing a line under a conversation that has gone off on a tangent.